# How to filter out the List of Objects? In Java 8

Tags: java, loops, iterator

Trimble API returns a list of Objects. For Example 2 objects. Object 1 and Object 2 have the same latitude and longitude but Object Has trimble ID but Object Two does not. I basically need to create a list that will remove the object latitude and longitude matches between and trimble ID is not present

Here is the code snippet that I tried but it does not work. It returns same number of objects

```
    public Vector<TrimblePlacesData> showModificationList(Vector<TrimblePlacesData> listOfTrimbleApiLocations) {

        Vector<TrimblePlacesData> customList = new Vector<>();
        System.out.println("Initial Size of the List: " + listOfTrimbleApiLocations.size());
        for (TrimblePlacesData place : listOfTrimbleApiLocations) {
            for (final Iterator<TrimblePlacesData> iter = customList.listIterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
                final TrimblePlacesData next = iter.next();

                boolean isLatitudeMatch = place.geometry.lat.equals(next.geometry.lat);
                boolean isLongitudeMatch = place.geometry.lon.equals(next.geometry.lon);
                boolean trimbleIDCheck = next.trimblePlaceId == null || next.trimblePlaceId.isEmpty();
                if (isLatitudeMatch && isLongitudeMatch && trimbleIDCheck) {
                    iter.remove();
                }
            }
            System.out.println(place);
            customList.add(place);
        }
        return customList;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If `trimblePlaceId` is a string you may need to check using the `StringUtils.isBlank()` method to also catch whitespace only values:

`isBlank(CharSequence cs)`: Checks if a CharSequence is empty (""), null or whitespace only.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a TreeMap to store uniques by lat/long with a merge function to preserve whichever has an ID:

```
TreeMap<TrimblePlacesData, TrimblePlacesData> map = new TreeMap<>(
        Comparator.comparing(p -> p.geometry.lat).thenComparing(p -> p.geometry.lon));

for (TrimblePlacesData place : listOfTrimbleApiLocations) {
    map.merge(place, place, (a, b) -> a.trimblePlaceId == null ? b : a);
}

return new Vector<>(map.values());
```